# How to use an arrow for slideToggle indicator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### CSS

```
#main_box{
width:300px;
height:20px;
border:1px solid #000000;
background-color:#FFCC00;
}
#slidingbox{
width:300px;
height:400px;
border:1px solid #000000;
background-color:#8AC007;
}
```

### SCRIPT

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#main_box").click(function(){
    $("#slidingbox").slideToggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

### HTML

```
</head>
<body>
<div id="main_box">Click to slide up and down</div>
<div id="slidingbox"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to add an arrow at the end of first div as an indicator which will change as the second div slides up and down.

Does any one know how to do it?

Comment: create two class with up and down arrow background image. Add a div with any one class at the end of first div. Now toggle the up and down arrow class on the same click event using toggleClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add two class for up and down arrows and toggle the class inside the heading click function.

```
 <div class="option-heading">
    <div class="arrow-up">&#9650;</div>
    <div class="arrow-down">&#9660;</div>
    heading 1
  </div>
  <div class="option-content">
      <p>content 1</p>
      <p>content 1</p>
      <p>content 1</p>
      <p>content 1</p>


  </div>
```

//css

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$(".option-content").hide();
$(".arrow-up").hide();
$(".option-heading").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".option-content").slideToggle(500);
        $(this).find(".arrow-up, .arrow-down").toggle();
});
```

});

//script

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$(".option-content").hide();
$(".arrow-up").hide();
$(".option-heading").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".option-content").slideToggle(500);
        $(this).find(".arrow-up, .arrow-down").toggle();
});
```

});

[Demo Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezhil/5ryweLn0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add pseudo element "after" arrow in the first div then create two class for both up and down.Each arrow contain different "content: url" css then add the  class to the div.

//html

```
<body>
      <div class="active" id="main_box">Click to slide up and down</div>
     <div id="slidingbox"></div>
  </body>
```

//script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#main_box").on("click",function(){
    $("#slidingbox").slideToggle('fast',function(){
        if ($('#slidingbox').is(':hidden')) {
            $("#main_box").removeClass('active')
            $("#main_box").addClass('in-active')
        }
        else{
            $("#main_box").removeClass('in-active')
            $("#main_box").addClass('active')
        }
    });
});

        });
```